# Emotion regulation & physical vulnerability to emotions

Tags: emotion

### Context

My question concerns the relationship between the Process Model of Emotion Regulation (Gross 1998) and the *management* of physical vulnerability to emotions, in particular as described in the literature on Dialectical Behavior Therapy (Dimeff & Linehan 2001).

[image]
(Illustration of the Process Model of Emotion Regulation (Gross 1998) taken from
[Peña-Sarrionandia et al. (2015)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272741226_Integrating_emotion_regulation_and_emotional_intelligence_traditions_A_meta-analysis/figures?lo=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic))

### Question

Does the *management* of physical vulnerability fall into the realm of the Process Model of Emotion Regulation (Gross 1998)?

If it does, to which family of emotion regulation strategies (e.g. "Situation Selection", "Situation Modification") does it correspond?

In that case, I would suspect it corresponds to "Situation Selection" (e.g. "time to relax"), but I am not sure.

By *management* of physical vulnerability to emotions, what I mean is:

- the use, on a daily basis, of basic strategies for the improvement of general physical and mental health (such as taking care of sleep hygiene, eating healthy, etc.)
- also the use of some more specific self-care strategies for the further improvement of well-being (such as massage, meditation, etc.)

I refer to the *management* of physical vulnerability to emotions as treated in the Dialectical Behavior Therapy literature (Dimeff & Linehan 2001).

This webpage provides a clear-cut presentation : https://dialecticalbehaviortherapy.com/emotion-regulation/emotions-physical-vulnerability/

### References

Dimeff, L., & Linehan, M. (2001). Dialectical behavior therapy in a nutshell. The California Psychologist, 34(3), 10-13.

Gross, J. J. (1998). The emerging field of emotion regulation: an integrative review.Rev. Gen. Psychol. 2, 271–299. doi: [10.1037/1089-2680.2.3.271](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1037/1089-2680.2.3.271)

Peña-Sarrionandia, A., Mikolajczak, M., & Gross, J. (2015). Integrating emotion regulation and emotional intelligence traditions: A meta-analysis. Frontiers in Psychology, 6, 160. doi: [10.3389/fpsyg.2015.00160](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2016-24215-001)